# Android CardView on 4.4.4, becomes transparent when animated or moved

Tags: android, android-layout, android-4.4-kitkat, android-cardview

While testing my app compatibility on all android APIs, I found the bug in android.support.v7.widget.CardView on android 4.4.4, whenever I try to animated it or use it in any other widget **it becomes transparent while it is animating or it is touched/moved**.

This happens only on android kitkat 4.4.4, and it works perfectly on all other API level, it works even on android 4.4.2

Anyone faced a similar problem or has a solution?

Layout containing the CardView

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/root_surprise"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.epollomes.lebaneseproverbs.fragments.SingleCategoryFragment">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view_title2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@drawable/surprise_me_menu"/>

<com.epollomes.lebaneseproverbs.fonts.FontFitTextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view_title_surprise"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:text="@string/hazzak_el_yom"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="50sp"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/card_view_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view_id2"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="25dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardColor"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        card_view:contentPadding="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/double_quote2"/>


            <com.epollomes.lebaneseproverbs.fonts.FontFitTextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewTest2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="15dp"
                android:text="test"
                android:textColor="@color/proverbColor"
                android:textSize="100sp"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/double_quote"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I tried removing all the parameters from inside the card view (except width and height), and also removed the the views inside the CardView's layout. Without any success.

The calling java code is a simple animation:

```
public void entranceAnimation() {
    Animation animFirst = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.surprise_animation);
    cardViewProverb.startAnimation(animFirst);
}
```

Any idea?

Thank you